# Self-similar matrices?

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra, fractals

Does anyone know anything about self-similar (infinite) matrices, with more or less fractal(-like) structure and admitting meaningful matrix-algebra operations?

Comment: Also, could the moderators or/and high-reputation users kindly add here a tag "fractals" or something like that?

Comment: How are they "self-similar" or "fractal"?  What Hilbert space are these operators acting on?

Comment: Well, John, give me some time to think how to explain this... Or, in the case if you can read some Russian, here are two short texts with examples of such matrices: http://csc.ac.ru/ej/file/4381 and http://csc.ac.ru/ej/file/4641 .

And thanks to Dmitri for creating the fractals tag!

Comment: The self-similar matrix seems to do with an L-system of fundamental group of the figure 8 knot.  Then you look at the trace of elements of this word in some SL(2,C) representation.  The traces are determinants of some other sequence of matrices, whose construction I do not understand.  You also get an invariant differential form!

Comment: Indeed this paper consists in a collection of facts and looks to me as sort of an unfinished scientific work, this is why I am searching for new ideas. And that sequence of matrices is constructed in a self-similar way: the elements of a finite matrix are replaced with some blocks of the like elements, then once more and so on. Here is where the self-similarity appears, although (alas) the fractal dimension of the set of nonzero elements in the resulting infinite matrix is just one. Nevertheless, it does look like a fractal, at least a bit...

Comment: This question should be closed, I think. If you can turn it into something more concrete with maybe a motivation and a small explanation, then I would be quite interested in reading it! As it stands, the answer is probably yes, as apparently *someone* knows *something* about that kind of matrices.

Comment: This depends on the aims of this site: if broad/general questions don't work here, then ok. Note however that this question has been for already almost 2 years on another math forum, and *nobody* could say *anything*. Note also that it is exactly such questions that stimulate research activity in people. Cheers

Comment: One more remark for Mariano and all the readers, after a little musing: posing a question in such a broad way also reflects my personal way of thinking. And, after having used this forum for just one day, I see that I like it so much, and don't want to quit... Maybe there is some way to settle this?

Comment: Igor. Let me give you an advise.  Expend a little bit this question. The majority of people who read you here are PhD students. Maybe you can explain one of the notions (what is a self-similar matrix? what is matrix algebra operation?), or maybe there is a refference, or an example. Though I like the question, it is really quite hard to get what it is about exactly. Of course, this is up to you -- if you want somebody to give an answer or not. By the way, if you modify your question, it will be again on the top of the list, more people will read it and more people will have some opinion :))

Comment: OK, Dmitri, I will do as you say: staying here, I must respect the rules of this forum. I was, however, a bit embarrassed having read, at the page "How to ask a good MO question", about vague and specific questions. It is definitely very sad that "vague" questions are forbidden, because, first, creative questions are always vague and, second, they reflect the way of thinking of some minority of scientists (I think, not only professors but PhD students as well). Anyhow, as I say, I will prepare soon a more detailed question.

Comment: "nobody could say anything" perhaps because the question was too vague?  Maybe they even had some information you're looking for, but they had no way to know it!

Comment: I'd like to see more background in the question (I don't read Russian) and I'd like to see it reopened.  It's fine with me if these events happen independently.

Comment: I had a similar idea, and ask myself if representations of p-adic groups would match your intuition?

Answer (score 2):

You should learn about the hyperfinite `II_1` factor, which is the limit of the inclusions

```
M_1 --> M_2 --> M_4 --> M_8 --> ....
```

(here `M_k` is the `k` by `k` matrices over $\mathbb{C}$) where each inclusion is given by tensoring with the identity matrix in `M_2`. Every 'finite' element is "self-similar" in a sense.

Comment: For the record, btw, I'm in the camp that thinks this is a poor question: too vague, and it's unclear what you mean by "self-similar". Moreover, not knowing whether this answer is basic stuff you already know, or somewthing new, I have little motivation to expand on it. 

Comment: Scott, thanks for you answer. I am just studying what this mathoverflow is, and your answer is helpful for this. Perhaps I will explain in the next version of my question that just tensor products are not "fractal enough" - or, otherwise, I may decide that this was a wrong site to ask serious questions. But thank you anyhow!

Comment: Igor, this is "the wrong site" to ask questions that are so vague that it's not clear what an answer would even look like! In a comment above you equate creativity with vagueness, but I don't see how creativity prevents you from defining the terms that you use in the question.

Comment: Henry, thanks for your comment. It you re-read my question, you will see that, essentially, I have already got the very clear answer, in the negative (nobody knows). My question was exactly what I wanted to ask: *anything vaguely resembling* self-similarity would work. So my question was very precise, including the fact that the definition of the terms was not fixed.

Comment: Igor, "anything vaguely resembling self-similarity would work" Except that Scott's answer vaguely resembles self-similarity, and apparently it doesn't work!  You could have saved Scott the trouble of giving an answer you didn't need if you'd given more details in the question.

Comment: Henry, yes, here I agree. Indeed, it was my oversight, I should have remarked about tensor products. Otherwise, I cannot see at this moment any more remarks overseen by me. But maybe this discussion with me was a bit entertaining for Scott? :)

Comment: Actually, mostly no --- I saw the high noise/signal discussion going on on meta, and gave an answer in order to more clearly highlight the fact that your question was too vague to receive a useful answer. :-)